# Identify Container Width

Tags: css

I need assistance finding the line of CSS I need to modify to increase the width of the main content container at smaller screen sizes. The problem I'm having is that in smaller screen widths the content does not extend to the width of the screen. Instead there is a pretty wide right hand margin. I would like to extend the content from the left side of the screen to the right to make better use of the screen space. Can someone tell me what line of code I need to change to fix this? Thank you!

The site is - https://www.shiftins.com

[image: Mobile responsive container width]

Comment: *cough* Google Chrome Developer Tools at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ *cough*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `styles.css`, line 2982:

```css
.content,
.content-sidebar-sidebar .content,
.content-sidebar-sidebar .content-sidebar-wrap,
.sidebar-content-sidebar .content,
.sidebar-content-sidebar .content-sidebar-wrap,
.sidebar-primary,
.sidebar-secondary,
.sidebar-sidebar-content .content,
.sidebar-sidebar-content .content-sidebar-wrap {
    width: 100%;
}
```

On line 1552:

```css
.page.sidebar-content .entry {
    padding: 40px 40px 40px 0;
}
```

Combined, these produce the effect you're seeing.

Changing the second rule to `padding: 40px 0 40px 0;` removes that large right padding but the form is still clipped. The form is contained in an `iframe` and is fixed at 500px wide. Based on the structure, I'm guessing the form is out of your control. Adding `min-width:500px;` to the second rule makes the page width wider than the screen, but prevents the clipping of the form.